# Replace Strings Synchronously?

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I'm still considered a beginner at programming. I'm creating a simple program to create "upside down" style text, but I have run into a problem I cannot solve.

I check a textbox and replace certain characters with String.Replace. But with the example here:

```
Input = Input.Replace("d", "p")  'Upside down d
....
Input = Input.Replace("p", "d")  'Upside down p
```

Makes all "d"s turn to "p"s then back to "d"s again. Is there another method to do this at the same time?

I appreciate an answer. Thanks.

Comment: There is no method that will be more efficient than what you have there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the characters one by one, building the new `String` in a `StringBuilder` or a `StringBuffer`, don't change the original `String` reference you got.

**Edit - Sample Code**

Here is a sample code, I don't really  remember the VB syntax but I suppose the below is correct:

```
Dim text As String = "Hello World"

Dim SB as new StringBuilder()

For Each c As Char in text
    If c = "a" Then SB.Append("ɐ")
    If c = "A" Then SB.Append("∀")

    ' ...
    ' ...
    ' The rest of your cases the same way
    ' ...

Next

text = StrReverse(SB.ToString())
```

Comment: I will look into this and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: I think I did this completely wrong, as it doesn't even need the StringBuilder. http://pastebin.com/ZTBZyFJ4 Could I possibly see an example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest (and really dirtiest) way to do it would be replacing "d" with an intermediate character like "#" and then replacing "#" with "p" at the end of the function

Edit: the "iterate on each character" is actually a much cleaner solution